# Deleting many-to-many: Flask-Sqlalchemy tries to delete every row with specific id

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm stuck on deleting many-to-many records from MySQL db using flask and flask-sqlalchemy. 
It seems as though sqlalchemy is trying to delete all rows from the relationship table where id of a is the same as linked to the b.

The error(example):

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'ksiazka_autor' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 0 were matched.
```

or

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'ksiazka_wydawnictwo' expected to delete 552 row(s); Only 551 were matched.

INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine DELETE FROM ksiazka_kategoria WHERE ksiazka_kategoria.ksiazka_id = %s AND ksiazka_kategoria.kategoria_id = %s
2017-08-29 15:44:34,965 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ((166, 40), (167, 40), (168, 40), (169, 40), (170, 40), (171, 40), (172, 40), (173, 40)  ... displaying 10 of 178 total bound parameter sets ...  (1463, 19), (2046, 19))
```

Relation tables:

```
ksiazka_autor = db.Table('ksiazka_autor',
        db.Column('autor_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('autor.id')),
        db.Column('ksiazka_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ksiazka.id'))
    )
        ksiazka_wydawnictwo = db.Table('ksiazka_wydawnictwo',
        db.Column('wydawnictwo_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('wydawnictwo.id')),
        db.Column('ksiazka_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ksiazka.id'))
    )
    ksiazka_ilustrator = db.Table('ksiazka_ilustrator',
        db.Column('ilustrator_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ilustrator.id')),
        db.Column('ksiazka_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ksiazka.id'))
    )
    ksiazka_kategoria = db.Table('ksiazka_kategoria',
        db.Column('ksiazka_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ksiazka.id')),
        db.Column('kategoria_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('kategoria.id'))
    )
```

And models:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ksiazka'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]

    authors = db.relationship('Author', secondary=ksiazka_autor, backref='authors', cascade="all", lazy='dynamic')
    category = db.relationship('Category', secondary=ksiazka_kategoria, backref='category', cascade="all", lazy='dynamic')
    publisher = db.relationship('Publisher', secondary=ksiazka_wydawnictwo, backref='publisher', cascade="all", lazy='dynamic')
    artist = db.relationship('Artist', secondary=ksiazka_ilustrator, backref='artist', cascade="all", lazy='dynamic')

class Author(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'autor'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    books = db.relationship('Book', secondary=ksiazka_autor, backref=db.backref('books'), lazy='joined')

class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'kategoria'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    cat_books = db.relationship('Book', secondary=ksiazka_kategoria, backref=db.backref('cat_books'), lazy='joined')

class Publisher(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wydawnictwo'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    pub_books = db.relationship('Book', secondary=ksiazka_wydawnictwo, backref=db.backref('pub_books'), lazy='joined')

class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ilustrator'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    [...]
    art_books = db.relationship('Book', secondary=ksiazka_ilustrator, backref=db.backref('art_books'), lazy='joined')
```

and finally the flask code:

```
@app.route('/delete/book/<id>')
def delete_book(id):
    book = Book.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    db.session.delete(book)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/home')
```

Comment: I think this is due to the ```cascade option``` you have in there, please refer to the doc and wisely choose the different behaviour on delete operation.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html

Comment: Well, initially I didn't have the " cascade="all" " element, and I was getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you've set up two separate relationships for each relationship that you wanted. You have a relationship called `Book.authors` and a backref called `Author.authors`, as well as a relationship called `Author.books` and a backref called `Book.books`. This doesn't work because they both operate on the `ksiazka_autor`, leading to the conflict that you are seeing. Same goes for all your other relationships.

What you want instead is to use the `back_populates` option:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    ...

    authors = db.relationship('Author', secondary=ksiazka_autor, back_populates='books', cascade="all", lazy='dynamic')

class Author(db.Model):
    ...
    books = db.relationship('Book', secondary=ksiazka_autor, back_populates='authors', lazy='joined')
```

Manually removing related instances and committing twice is not the correct solution.

Comment: This answer just saved my day! However, I still need to understand a little better the role of the 'lazy' attribute in this context.

Comment: @AlmirCampos The `lazy` option was copied directly from the question. If you don't need the `lazy` option (or even know what it is) you can safely ignore it. Docs for the `lazy` option are available at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html